# Line crossing borders

Tags: css

I would like to have a border around my page witch are dashed. In the corners I would like the lines to cross. This is what I got so far:

```css
#main {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dashed;
    margin: 10px !important;
}
```

The lines are not crossing. Is there anyone who knows how to do this? Thanks

Comment: short answer - not possible in pure CSS, becaue it has no instruments to control the dashes/spaces between them etc. But you can create an image of crossing borders and place it in the corners

Comment: Obligatory mdn link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image